# iPad PDF software to edit, merge, annotate etc well PDF documents like in desktop? Also working with Math formulae?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, pdf

*This thread is a part of the major thread about using iPad for education purposes [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74399/how-to-read-and-write-with-ipad-ipad-for-studying-required-styluses-and-apps).*

This thread [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/what-software-is-available-preferably-free-to-create-and-edit-pdf-files-on-mac) made me realize that that it would be super-cool to be able to merge PDF documents and other documents in iPad.

**Helper questions**

> 1. How can I do it with documents of different formats?
> 2. Does there exist an app to merge PDF documents?
> 3. Possible to merge images or even Doc/Docx -documents with Math -formulae?

Comment: Questions on this site are stand-alone entities. They aren't part of "threads", but they do contain a single coherent question in the body of the post. They also don't contain random hyphens inserted at odd places.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at PDF Merger? It can read .doc and various image formats.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdf-merger/id453413252?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

*I am trying to summarize and categorize here things.*

There are general program such as GoodReader that are not good in small things such as searching or merging but good in reading with things such as light-adjustion. This is probably because the iPad's screen-area is limited, better to do a specific thing very well instead of many things poorly. I will list below more specific apps in iPad but many of them such as PDF Expert have iPhone version so iOS apps in that sense. Have a good reading!

[image]

I think if you want to do things very well in iPad you need to follow some sort of Unix-philosophy: less is more. Limitations such as area and virtual keyboard set clear design-guidelines such as avoiding extraneous things. New features always have trade-offs -- often in hard-to-measure things such as usability and accessibility. Despite lacking some objectiveness here I will outline apps in categories below. Please, feel free to suggest better categorization. You may find this thread [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/ipad-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand/204393#204393) useful if you are new with iPad, iOS i or Apple ecosystem.

**I. Apps prone in Reading**

> I. Papers app with things such as reference-lookup, grading and academic preview
>
> II. GoodReader app with things such as Light-adjusting
>
> III. Side-by-side app with cool intention but works badly, unfortunately no better alternative yet.

**III. Apps prone in searching such as Content-search over all documents**

> I. PDF Expert
>
> > It has a content-search and indexation, may create downtime in copying DropBox things elsewhere -- a lot of small files apparently.
> >
> > [image]
>
> More about apps with content-search [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68849/ipad-app-to-search-all-content-in-pdf-files).

**IV. Apps with good support for formats such as mathematical formulae**

> I. iAnnotate
>
> > iAnnotate is the only one currently able to read Windows proprietary formats well. Yes, I know: this is a bit painful particularly if you face this kind of files every now-and-then, you cannot yet find a killer app good in everything for iPad! For this kind of cases, iAnnotate helps you to see the math -formulae but you still need a desktop for editing or pay for Microsoft to edit the formats online.

Comment: I don't know if it does merging, but GoodReader does PDF annotations and it reads a bunch of different formats, so it deserves a mention in section 2.

Comment: @MarkThalman added it to the section `"I. Prone in reading..."`, there is some overlap here-and-there but there are still apps better in one thing than others. Is this categorization fine?